# What languages would be a good replacement for Java?

Tags: java, python, qt, programming-languages, replace

I may be posting a premature question, and maybe I'm just freaking out for no reason, but the way Oracle is handling Java is not very promising. I am a nerd who fell in love with Java from the first sight, and use it all the time in my personal/freelance projects but now I am thinking of a replacement.

I am fluent in C#/VB.NET too but I am looking for something more like:

1. Open Source
2. Compiled
3. Cross-Platform
4. Object Oriented
5. Large standard library
6. Extensive documentation
7. Web development is a major plus

I was thinking about a compromise: Python/Django for web development (or PHP), and Qt for thick client development. Anyone with better thoughts?

Comment: Are you interested in leaving the JVM or just the Java programming language?

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and say you're freaking out for no reason.

Comment: "the way Oracle is handeling Java is not very promising" - care to elaborate?

Comment: Why not use open source implementations of java?

Comment: I am intersted in leaving the JVM

Comment: @Rob Hruska I am not making points here, just looking if there is other alternatives..

Comment: @Rob Hruska, he probably pointing to the recent Oracle suing Google thingie

Comment: sounds like you are looking for C++ and boost perhaps?

Comment: @aaa: Maybe I'm ignorant (so let me know - I'd be interested to see what's out there), but I didn't know there was much webdev (OP's point #7) done in C++/boost.

Comment: @Fru to be honest, I am just as ignorant.  however, google seems to get by using C++/python stack.

Comment: @aaa: Of course, Google has uses plenty of Java too, which is kind of what prompted this question...

Comment: @Jus no language I am aware of satisfies all points listed (depending on definition of compiled).  except for web development (listed as major plus) C++ fits in okay

Comment: How is Oracle handling Java ? If you are referring to the Oracle vs. Google lawsuit, you should realize that there are no innocents in this game, and google is far from being an open-source angel. If you stick to the language, and you do not consider writing your own JVM, I assure you that there is nothing Oracle or any other corp. can do against you!

Comment: Your question reminds of all other people who think that world will end in 2012. NOM

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not so long ago, I decided to explore away from the JVM. I set foot on python, and even though i'm nowhere near the expert/ guru level, I dont regret it. Didn't choose C# (considered it) because I consider it to be more of the same. I alredy know (and like a lot) C++, so python seemed like something new, which is what I was looking for.

It fullfils many of your requirements. Particularly, i'm decided not to learn PHP, so the web frameworks in python came in great.

Not to mention, Python has a large [community](http://www.python.org/community/) (also see [here](http://www.pycon.org/)), always eager to help and teach, which I consider to be very important.

Just my two cents.

Comment: It is not compiled. But otherwise, it fits all points perfectly. Because of this (and because I'm a Python fan), +1

Comment: @aaa I don't think this counts as compilation. Well, strictly speaking, it does, but most of the time, people say "compilation" and really mean "native compilation".

Comment: Pick Python and don't even thing about PHP! I'm serious. I had to leave PHP because it's just a big pile of mess. +1 to python.

Comment: Well I don't mean Native Compilation... an intermediate form is OK

Comment: @del sure, just want to clarify.  personally, long time I thought python was interpreted :-(

Comment: Plus you have Jython so you can always repent and come back.

Comment: Most Java implementations compile to (JVM) bytecode too - so by the same argument you can't call java compiled either.

Comment: Yeah, I found Python's features is the closest to Java's features.

Answer (score 6):

Might be worth loking at the other JVM languages - Clojure and Scala are the two I personally think are most promising.

Yes you are on the JVM, but you're pretty independent from Java the langauage and don't have to use any Sun/Oracle implementations if you don't want to.

Having said that - I think that you are worrying a little too much about Java, too many players (including Oracle!) have too much invested to let it go too far off course.

Comment: When I said Java I meant eh JVM ... so thanks for your thoughts, but no :)

Answer (score 3):

Try [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/). It looks extremely elegant and promising. Being object oriented and sharing a lot with java in a very concise manner.

Comment: The OP commented: "I am intersted in leaving the JVM"

Comment: Doesnt Scala run on the JVM ?

Comment: exactly @Tom, by Java i meant the JVM

Comment: There is also a CLR version of scala (though I don't know how up-to-date or stable it is).

Comment: My understanding is that the .Net version of Scala (more or less) only gets worked on when Microsoft pays someone to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you said points to C#, except for the Open Source point.

To fix that, there's [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Comment: yeah have you tried Mono on linux ??
+ Mono is not **really** an open-source implementation !! have you seen any other open Source CLR implementation ? NO becose MS is M$.
+ Mono is useless without all the **cool** libraries of .NET: WCF, WWF, WPF... etc
Sorry but it's just my opinion!

Comment: Agreeing with @FearUs, with mono you get open source, but you lose the large standard library.

Answer (score 2):

You could try D.  My one-sentence description of why it's an awesome language is that its generic programming/compile-time introspection/template metaprogramming facilities are good enough to give you almost flexibility of a duck-typed language, while its execution speed and static type checking rival or exceed C++ and C#.

I think it meets your requirements quite well.

- Open source:  The frontend to the reference DMD implementation is open source (the back end isn't due to restrictions beyond the author's control).  Work is underway to glue the reference frontend to open source backends such as LLVM (LDC) and GCC (GDC).  In the case of D1 (the older version of the language) the LLVM port is fairly mature.
- Compiled:  D is meant to be compiled to native machine code, i.e. raw, inscrutable hexadecimal numbers.
- Cross-platform:  The reference DMD compiler supports x86 Windows, Linux, Mac OS X and FreeBSD.  GDC and LDC will likely support a lot more CPU architectures.
- Object oriented:  D isn't a "pure" OO language in the Ruby sense of everything being an object, or in the Java sense of not supporting any other paradigm.  It does, however, fully support Java-style OO as a subset of the language, along with procedural and functional style programming.
- Large standard library:  D1 has Tango, which qualifies.  D2 has Phobos, which is not "large" yet by modern standards but is larger than C or C++'s standard lib.  However, recently there has been a large interest in contributing and Andrei Alexandrescu (its main designer) has accepted several new contributors, including myself.
- Extensive documentation:  The standard library and language are reasonably well documented at the Digital Mars website.  There's also Andrei Alexandrescu's book ["The D Programming Language"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635361).
- Web development:   This is an admitted weakness.  D doesn't (yet) have a good web framework, though its native unicode support and excellent generic programming support should make writing one relatively easy.

Answer (score 1):

I too would like another Java-like technology to come along.  Lately I've been doing Flex/Actionscript.  While I really enjoy it, Actionscript technology seriously lacks the elegance that Java has.  Adobe can write some good cross platform APIs, but they just don't have the head capital to build elegant languages and compilers.  I've also tried Ruby, but the VM for Ruby is really bad.  I've gone back to Java after my flirtation with other technologies and I think it's because the language is good enough, but the JVM is by far the best out there.

So do you want to stay with the JVM or do you really want to the leave the JVM altogether?  Staying on the JVM there are lots of options: JRuby, Scala, Groovy, Javascript, Clojure are the big players.  However, there are tons of great languages that can take advantage of the JVM's features.

Leaving the JVM there are still good options like python, ruby, and erlang.  But you give up some of the nice features of the JVM like performance (big one), and the ability to drop down to a nice language like Java if you need speed.  Those others mean using C or nothing at all.

I finally stopped worrying about Java's future.  Sun did all it could to screw it up and it still turned out pretty darn good.  I think Opensource has a lot more influence over Java's success than Oracle or Sun could ever have had.

Answer (score 1):

I can't post comments yet, so I'm posting an answer related to the Python discussion. Though Python isn't compiled to machine code, there is a Python-to-C compiler called [Cython](http://cython.org), which can compile nearly all valid Python -- closures are finally (!) in the latest development release.  It's have a big impact on some parts of the Python commmunity, e.g., I was at Euroscipy recently, and over half the talks mentioned Cython.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like PHP, but it does meet all of your requirements. It doesn't officially support compilation but there is the [Hip Hop](http://wiki.github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/) project which compiles PHP to C code. Facebook is currently heading up this project.

That said, I highly discourage you from using it :)

Answer (score 0):

C# is the only thing that will meet your needs and not feel hopelessly archaic, or frustrate with limited library. For open source/non-windows, use mono. It's a good, mature implementation of most of what's important in the CLR.

Some things (WPF, WCF, etc) are "missing" from mono, but these aren't so much part of the platform as they are windows-specific proprietary toolkits. Some of them are being implemented slowly in mono, some aren't. Coming from java you won't miss them because you're looking for a platform and good standard libraries to build upon, not a gui toolkit or whiz-bang communication framework.

As far as a platform to build stuff with that's "like" java and offers similar levels of functionality, C# + CLR is the clearest option.

Comment: hmm.. Have you tried Mono? I mean Have you tried it on a real project targeting both Linux and Windows ?? Mono + GTK# ?? Because I did, and eventually it ended up doing a Netbeans RCP application instead (It's Java BTW). But hey, thanks for your response !

Answer (score 0):

Using also Cython you get the best of the two worlds , the ability to code in python , the ability to code in C and C++ and of course compile your code and the ability to use both python a c/c++ libraries out of the box. And if you dont like C++ syntax , cython syntax is python syntax and more.

[link text](http://www.cython.org/)